# How do I use insertObjectAtIndex?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to insert a string into a particular place in an NSMutableArray so I have done
`[myMutableArray insertObject:newString atIndex:219];` 
By the way, when I do `[myMutableArray count]` it returns 273 so I know that there are enough elements.  The problem, however, is that every time I try this it gives an NSRangeException.  The weird part is that when I log `[myMutableArray class]` it returns *_*_NSArrayM, but when the exception shows up it says that I'm calling [__NSCFString insertString:atIndex:] and that is where the error is coming from.  I am definitely using insertObject though, and it is definitely a mutable array.  Does anyone know what my problem might be?  Also, when I use breakpoints it highlights the first bit of code that I posted, so that's where the exception is.

```
allIDs = [self allIDs];
[allIDs insertObject:[newStudent idNumber] atIndex:x];

- (NSMutableArray*) allIDs
{
    if (!allIDs) {
        allIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    filePath = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    filePath = [[self getDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"List of Student IDs"];
    NSString *txtInFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];

    if(!txtInFile) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableString *tempName = [NSMutableString string];

    for (int i = 0; i < [txtInFile length]; i++) {

        if ([txtInFile characterAtIndex:i] == '*') {

            [allIDs addObject:tempName];

            tempName = [NSMutableString string];
        } else {
            [tempName appendFormat:@"%c", [txtInFile characterAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }

    return allIDs;
}
```

So I went back and looped through inserting it at all indexes up to 219 and I printed out the index to see what index it started throwing exceptions at.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 219; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%i", i);
    [allIDs insertObject:newStudent.idNumber atIndex:i];
}
```

For some reason it printed everything up to 218 with no problem and then it skipped to 801505682082758655 and logged that lots of times before coming up with an out of range exception

Comment: can you provide some actual code?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella here is some of the actual code.  I think that this is all that would be relevant, but I mostly taught myself programming so I'm afraid I might not follow a lot of standard procedures.  If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: How are you defining `allIDs`? Do you synthesize it? Are you doing `allIDs = ` anywhere else? Does it always crash or only sometimes?

Comment: Maybe some context around where you are creating newStudent. (And is idNumber a custom getter or synthesized one?)

Comment: @Wain allIDs is defined in the header but not synthesized, and yes, but [self allIDs] is the only thing it's ever set to.

Comment: @Rakesh idNumber is a synthesized property of type NSString.  Also, newStudent is an argument of the method in which it is used.  I just checked though and the argument passed in is definitely correct.

Comment: `filePath = [[NSString alloc] init];` followed immediately by `filePath = ....;` makes no sense.  That first assignment is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error says that it is a call to `insertString:atIndex:` that is causing the exception, then it is that call and has nothing to do with `insertObject:atIndex:`.   Quite specifically, it is giving a range exception when calling `insertString:atIndex:` on an **NSCFString**.   Thus, nothing to do with your array.

When you have a crash, there is a backtrace.  Post it.  That includes exceptions.   As well, you can create an exception breakpoint in the debugger quite easily.   Set one and then see where the code breaks.

Unless you are using ARC, that code is quite leaky.   Even if using ARC, there are some issues there.   Namely, this makes no sense:

```
filePath = [[NSString alloc] init];
filePath = [[self getDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"List of Student IDs"];
```

There is no need to `filePath = [[NSString alloc] init];`.

Comment: I am using ARC and for some reason this time when I used breakpoints it highlighted something else... I have no clue why but what it highlighted actually makes sense this time.

Comment: @user1654889 Great!  Glad you found your issue;  make sure you understand the whole thing about initializing `filePath`, too.  I'm betting you followed the "tuts plus" Objective-C tutorial?   It is wildly wrong on a number of counts.